# Why the ListView collapse when put in a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have read the all the answers here:[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)But it seems no one cares why the ListView get collapsed when put in a ScrollView.I think something happens to the onMeasure() method but I'm not sure of it.So,does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just a suggestion, a list inside a scroll view is most of the time (if not always) a bad idea :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,and I will pay more attention to it.But do you have any idea why the listview collapses?

Comment: You should avoid that. Explaining your context maybe can help us to suggest an alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

Your aproach is not very good. As you did't describe your situation, i can't say exactly what you need. But anyway i will suggest to use Headers and footers instead of puttings scrollable listView in ScrollView. But if you  need that anyway, i suggest to use RecyclerView and NestedScrollView instead, as it handles a lot of scrolling issues.

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

[NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support putting scrollable UI component as a child to other scrolable UI component. Since `ListView` is scrollable by default, that might be the problem. Hence, all the suggestions not to use `ListView` as a child to `ScrollView`